# Where does the SI pointer point to when it is specified to point to an offset?

Tags: pointers, assembly, indexing, x86, memory-segmentation

Apologies in advance if this is a duplicate question. I am a little confused the following code:

```
list db 80h, 70h, 60h, 50h, 40h, 30h, 20h

       mov si, offset list
       move al,[si] 
repit: inc si
       add al,[si]
       jnc repit
fin:
```

I know that `jnc` indicates that we will exit this loop when there is no carry overflow, i.e., `CF = 0`. Since `si` is supposed to point to the index of the first element of the list, wouldn't this be 80h? And then if `si` is incremented, it should then point to 70h. Upon adding these together, the answer should be F0, correct? However, when I run the chunk of code, I get the value of AL to be 50. How is this possible? What am I missing? Thank you all in advance!

Comment: You have the loop condition backwards.  You keep looping as long as there is no carry-out.  You exit when the `c` condition (CF==1) is true.

Answer (score 3):

> I know that jnc indicates that we will exit this loop when there is no carry overflow, i.e., CF = 0.

This is not correct. `JNC` will jump, if CF=0, what means it will jump if there is no *unsigned overflow*.

> Since si is supposed to point to the index of the first element of the list, wouldn't this be 80h? And then if si is incremented, it should then point to 70h. Upon adding these together, the answer should be F0, correct?

So far, yes.

> However, when I run the chunk of code, I get the value of AL to be 50.  How is this possible?
>   What am I missing?

The return value of 50h is

```
80h + 70h + 60h = 50h + CARRY flag (unsigned overflow).
```

Step-by-step it is

```
80h + 70h = F0h    (CF = 0 = JUMP)
F0h + 60h = 50h    (CF = 1 = NO JUMP = EXIT LOOP)
```

So the last addition sets the CARRY flag to `1` because of an *unsigned overflow* from FFh to 00h (F0h + 0Fh to F0h + 10h (and finally 60h - 10h =  50h)). Because the CARRY flag is set, the conditional `JNC` jump passes and `AL` does contain the "overflowed" value of 50h.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the title question (which is barely related to the rest of your question):

> Where does the SI pointer point to when it is specified to point to an offset?

In x86's segmented memory model, near pointers *are* offsets relative to a segment base.  `mov si, OFFSET symbol` sets SI to the offset part of the `seg:off` address of `symbol`.

If `symbol` is label in the data section of your program, and you use `[SI]` while the `DS` segment base = the start of that section, then `[SI]` gives you the byte(s) at `symbol` as a memory operand.

**SI doesn't *point to* an offset, it *holds* an offset after `mov si, OFFSET symbol`.  This *is* a pointer.**

---

In a simple flat memory model (like 32 or 64-bit code), everything uses base=0, so offset = linear address.

In 16-bit code with a "tiny" memory model (like a `.com`), CS=DS=ES=SS so all memory references use the same base.  Again, just the 16-bit offset works as a complete pointer.  It doesn't matter what the actual segment base is because everything is relative to it.